# Javascript/Jquery simple user experience functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am starting to write some javascript for my site to create a better user experience but i am getting a little confused on what exactly is happening, and maybe it is clearly evident to someone else what I am doing wrong or missing. I have two javascript functions that work perfect after the first time of use and if you use it slowly (sometimes it skips the next item and selects nothing if you press two keys too fast). I feel that I am missing some sort of $(document).ready(function() {}); implementation to make sure that each process has finished before it moves on. I have two textboxes that the user puts in two numbers then it moves on to the next tab element (the next textbox). The textboxes are also in an asp.net update panel if that has any impact.

```
    function selectall(item) {
            $(item).focus().select();
    };

    function selectNext(textBox) {
        if ($(textBox).val().length == 2) {
            $(textBox).next().focus().select();
        }
    };

        <asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" Width="30px" AutoPostBack="True"  onkeyup="selectNext(this);" onclick="selectall(this);"
    Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Text2" runat="server" Width="30px" AutoPostBack="True" onkeyup="selectNext(this);" onclick="selectall(this);"
    Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="Text2" runat="server"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to contain the textboxes in an UpdatePanel?

It's possible that the AutoPostback you have set on your textboxes is causing issues with your jQuery since a page post back will occur whenever the TextBox control loses focus.

I would take your textboxes out of your UpdatePanel, remove the AutoPostback and place your JavaScript in a `document.ready`.

## Edit

Code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fname").keyup(function() {
        selectNext($(this));
    });

    $("#fname").focus(function() {
        $(this).select();
    });

    $("#lname").keyup(function() {
        selectNext($(this));
    });

    $("#lname").click(function() {
        $(this).select();
    });
});

function selectNext(textBox) {
    if (textBox.val().length == 2) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            textBox.next().focus().select();
        }, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: These textboxes are in an update panel because it is part of a jquery dialog pop up for some user input that needs to post back to the server to fill some data in c# functions before it loads for the user. so these textboxes start with two numbers as well. 

Thank you for pointing out the autopostback I had, this did solve the first use issue where it wouldnt work the first time, but if you still lift the key up to fast it will skip over the next text box.

Comment: I should also mention I utilize the .blockui function to lock the page until they respond to this dialog pop up div and click submit or cancel. and when i put $(document).ready(function() { }); around my functions the google console says it cant find these script functions.

Comment: I believe this skipping problem has something to do with the onkeyup event, because it may switch to the next box before you release the key up fully? triggering the next text boxes key up event? so somehow its the same key up event for both textboxes? is my best guess

Comment: @Mootz, is it something along the lines of this you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/sbhomra/taFUy/? A quick jsFiddle I created.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for taking the time to try and find a solution for me. I have been playing with it a lot more and it seems your fiddle has the same problem as my js does. If you try pressing two numbers as fast as possible in the first box, it skips your middle box completely and goes to the drop down, exact problem I am having. I dont think its that big of a deal, but details like this bother me greatly. haha